# JAXB generateElementProperty code location

Tags: java, jaxb, wsdl

I'm a C# developer, but recently I had to rewrite a version of my app in Java.

The C# app works with a WCF host/client transmitting custom objects. Since Java is not my specialty I struggled a little to create a working web service that communicated with my WCF host, but I managed to do it. In the process of parsing the WCF custom objects, apparently, Java does most of the work for me, creating all the classes and objects.

However, in any `String` property of my custom object, it defined it as an `JAXBElement`. Each of the others properties in this generated class are saved to an XML file, except for those created as "JAXB" properties.

Searching the web I found several articles declaring that the following code would prevent the generation of such property type (leaving only the original property type, in my case String)

```xml
<jaxb:bindings version="2.0"
        xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="schema-importedby-wcfsvcwsdl"
             node="/xs:schema">
    <jaxb:globalBindings generateElementProperty="false"/>
  </jxb:bindings>
```

The only problem is that it doesn't say where do I put this code. In my project I have several wsdl and xml files, and though I tried it in a few, none seems to work.

Thanks

Comment: Can you share the relevant part of the schema?  This sort of thing often shows up when you have an element that is both optional and nillable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add parameter to generation tool - *xjc*.

- save **bindings.xml** file

> ```
> <jaxb:bindings version="2.0" 
> xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" 
> xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc" 
> xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"> 
>     <jaxb:bindings node="/xs:schema"> 
>         <jaxb:globalBindings generateElementProperty="false"/> 
>     </jaxb:bindings> 
> </jaxb:bindings>
> ```

- in console / tool add parameter :

  xjc -verbose **-b bindings.xml** -wsdl my_wsdl_from_c_sharp.wsdl ...

or if you use wsdl2java: wsdl2java **-b bindings.xml** ...

Comment: what do you mean "add parameter to generation tool -xjc"?? I'm using NetBeans 7.2 and I didn't find anything like that?? Please keep in mind that java is not exactly my area. Thanks

Comment: choose New > Other > XML > JAXB Binding. Then click Next. The New JAXB Binding wizard appears. There on the bottom you have "Use binding file"

Comment: Just a short note one the file name: Although the name of the file doesn't matter, the typical extension is `.xjb.`. See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html#wp148366